# strange permission error involving ssh, Cygwin, Windows 7, and .sh files

Tags: ssh, permissions, cygwin, openssh

I am new to Cygwin, ssh, and messing with file permissions and have a problem. On computer WORKER1, I am attempting to ssh into computer WORKER2 and then running a .sh file on WORKER1 from there. From what I can tell from the below output, ls -l shows that there should be permission to do everything (I know that those are bad permissions to have, but I was going mad trying to figure out why I was getting this permission error).

```
root@Worker1 ~
$ ssh WORKER2
Last login: Tue Jan 31 10:51:54 2012 from worker1

root@Worker2 ~
$ cd //WORKER1/Users/Public/pMatlab/MatlabMPI/Examples/MatMPI

root@Worker2 //WORKER1/Users/Public/pMatlab/MatlabMPI/Examples/MatMPI
$ sh Dos_Commands.WORKER2.1.sh
sh: Dos_Commands.WORKER2.1.sh: Permission denied

root@Worker2 //WORKER1/Users/Public/pMatlab/MatlabMPI/Examples/MatMPI
$ ls -l
total 28
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 Administrators None   2 Jan 31 11:01 Dos_Commands.WORKER1.0
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 Administrators None 127 Jan 31 11:01 Dos_Commands.WORKER2.1
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 Administrators None 250 Jan 31 11:01 Dos_Commands.bat
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 Administrators None 636 Jan 31 11:01 MPI_COMM_WORLD.mat
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 Administrators None  97 Jan 31 11:01 MatMPIdefs1.m
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 Administrators None 199 Jan 31 11:01 p0_p0_t10000_buffer.ma
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 Administrators None 199 Jan 31 11:01 p0_p1_t10000_buffer.ma
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 Administrators None   0 Jan 31 11:01 p0_p1_t10000_lock.mat
```

Both computers are running Windows 7 64 bit, and I am running the latest version of Cygwin and OpenSSH on each. The sshd running on WORKER2 is also the one from Cygwin. When installing sshd, the only way I was able to get it to properly function was to answer 'no' to privilege separation and 'yes' to installing as a service when running ssh-host-config. I'm using public key RSA authentication. I've tried mounting //WORKER1/Users/Public/pMatlab/ as a network drive and accessing it that way, but that did not help either. Any ideas of what might be going wrong? Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that my network sharing settings in Windows are set to allow everything from what I can see. Furthermore, my Public folder and folders within it all seem to be set to read-only (in the right click->Properties menu), though the files within it are not. Attempting to change this in the Properties menu does nothing - when I turn read-only off it is just back on again when I reopen the Properties menu. I tried changing this by running attrib -r C:\Users\Public in cmd.exe but that did not do anything either.

Finally, I do not get a permission denied error when running the .sh file locally, when I try to access it from the Windows GUI on computer WORKER2, or when I ssh from WORKER2 to itself and then try to access it. The permission error only appears when I ssh from WORKER1 to WORKER2 and then try to access the file on WORKER1 from there.

Final edit: Issue solved. It turned out that the folder was encrypted! No idea why. That's how it came out of the zip file for some reason.

Comment: [The read-only folder question has been addressed umpteen times before on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/search?q=read-only+folder+windows).  Please don't duplicate it.  SuperUser's search box is your friend.

Comment: Thanks - I was including it as additional information in case it is helpful. As I said, the files are not marked read-only so I think it may be unrelated but I felt that it was better to include more information rather than less.

Answer (score 5):

### Welcome to the wonderful new Unix world of 1989!

Those nice TRUSIX people have — just this year — defined an extension to the `ls` command to indicate visually when the `rwxrwxrwx` permissions information is not actually the whole of the story.  That extension is a `+` character following the permission flags.  As you can see, your `ls` output has `+` characters all over the place.  That means that your files have these new-fangled *discretionary access control list* thingies that the TRUSIX people are so excited about.  As such, your access to the files is *not* necessarily what you can deduce from the nine permissions flags alone.

To compensate for these limitations of old-style Unix tools in the face of the new-style ACLs, the TRUSIX people have also come up with a couple of new commands, `getacl` and `setacl`.  The former is used for looking at those ACLs.  I hear murmurings that people might prefer [`getfacl`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/getfacl.html) and [`setfacl`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setfacl.html) as names.  And there's a rumour going around that Microsoft's and IBM's OS/2 version 3 that's on the drawing board might eventually end up with commands named `cacls` and `xcacls` for looking at ACLs that will be *even better* than `getfacl` on their "New Technology" operating system, because they'll not present them through a 3-bit Unix lens but rather how they really are in all of their [standard-and-specific-rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff538834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [`drctpoxfew`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754) both-account-**and**-machine-name glory.

This idea is bound to catch on like wildfire, in the Unix world that everyone will surely end up a part of in the 1990s.  It's very likely that in 20 years time nine bits of permissions will seem old-hat and passé, ACLs will be the norm, and [even the fuddy-duddies that still look at nine permissions flags will know about them](http://cygwin.com./cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html). ☺

#### Further reading

- Craig Rubin (1989-08-18).  [*Rationale for Selecting Access Control List Features for the Unix System*](http://fas.org./irp/nsa/rainbow/tg020-a.htm).  NCSC-TG-020-A.  DIANE Publishing.  ISBN 9780788105548.
- Microsoft corporation (2008-05-08). [*User cannot access a file or folder but should have permission*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc773004%28WS.10%29.aspx).  TechNet.

Comment: Hahaha, that was fun to read *and* informative. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer. In the intervening years, the good people at Microsoft have also given us `icacls` -- and more recently `Get-Acl` in PowerShell (combining the best parts of VMS and Unix shells with native Windows APIs).